# Separate first letter with array in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a array called **tableData** who I put inside a tableView

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Andre",@"Alessandro",@"bruno",@"caio",@"Marcio",@"Maria",@"Jose", nil];
```

We can see that the array is in alphabetical order, I put this array inside a UITableView with this code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ID HERE";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

All I want to do is create a separator in UITableView showing the first letter of strings, Example:

```
Letter A --> This is a separator in TableView
Andre -> this is a row
Alessandro -> This is a row
Letter B -> This is another separator
Bruno -> this is a row
Letter C -> Another separator
Caio -> this is a another row
```

How I can do this? Have a method inside UITableViewDelegade that can do it for me? Have others solutions?

Comment: May I suggest using an [Indexed TableView](http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/)?

Comment: Page found I will see this link!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two steps:

1. As you aren't sure there will be a complete 24 alphabet characters, you need to skim the tableData to get the list of all existed first letter. Pay attention to upper and lower case.
2. For now you have two arrays, one is your tableData, the left that contains the list of first letter, lets call it arrayFirstLetters. Just use table section (you can find a lot of tutorial on google).

Answer (score -1):

try using table sections

here you can find a tutorial

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/